# where is my android database?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

i created an android application on eclipse where i made a database(just for testing) and i have to use that database in the final application to get and store information from the app. but most importantly i have to be able to share that database with others. and i cant find the file to be shared. i dont have much knowledge of sql but i thought they were stored in .db format so i tried to search for it but couldnt find the file. i can see the entries but not the file.

i also ran the app on my phone and i still could not find the database file, instead i found the database files of other apps like whatsapp.

so, where is my database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you are using emulator or real device, you can use **DDMS**(*Window-> open perspective-> DDMS*) to navigate the DB.

In DDMS, there is a **File Explorer**( If not visible, *window-> show view-> File Explorer* ).

Now there, you can navigate to the db as `/data/data/<app-package-name>/databases/<database-name>`

Now, to save the file, click on save button at top right corner of File Explorer.

**Update:**

Actually, before a table row insertion, I can't see the data base. If you want a static table with predefined data, you can do insertion at the time of table creation. Eg:- Refer `onCreate()` method->

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

SQLiteDatabase db;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "pics.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table picture(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,pics varchar(20))");
    db.execSQL("insert into picture values(1001,'one.jpg')");
    db.execSQL("insert into picture values(1002,'two.jpg')");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public long insert(ContentValues cv) {
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    long l=db.insert("picture", null, cv);
    db.close();
    return l;

}
public Cursor getAllValues() {
    db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.query("picture", null, null, null, null, null, "_id");
        db.close();
        return cr;
    }

}
```

Comment: what if i want a database in my application in the first place. like i make a list of questions and options for the final application to display. how can i do that?

Comment: You can do insertion at the same time of table creation.

Comment: but for insertion i need to have those questions on the program, and if i have that on my program i don't need the database. secondly, i will have around 1000 questions how am i supposed to write all that.

Comment: First of all, Database is a part of the program, used for data persistence. (ie, data remains unchanged even after app closed). Now, if you have 'static' questions(never change), then the way preferred is as in my answer. And if you have 'dynamic' questions, go for a client-server application. There also you have to type it at server side.

Comment: just one last question : how do i add thousands of questions to my database. i was thinking of creating a database of all the questions before publishing the app and using that to get questions. but still where do i write all the questions.like a text file or the program itself.

Comment: I think, writing inside program is better(if questions don't change). So db will be created automatically at first time app launch in every device.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the database you created on the internal storage of your device:

```
/data/data/<app-package-name>/databases/<database-name>
```

You need to be root to see that file with a file explorer.

Comment: i want to make a database that contains a series of questions to be displayed by the application, and i would have to make the entries before publishing the app. how can i do that?